# How can I add a column in R whose values reference a column in a different data frame?

Tags: r

So I have an R script that ranks college football teams. It outputs a rating and I want to take that rating from a different data frame and add it as a new column to a different data frame containing info from the upcoming week of games. Here's what I'm currently trying to do:

```
random_numbers <- rnorm(130, mean = mean_value, sd = sd_value)
sample_1 <- as.vector(sample(random_numbers, 1, replace = TRUE))
upcoming_games_df <- upcoming_games_df %>%
  mutate(home_rating = case_when(home_team %in% Ratings$team ~ Ratings$Rating[Ratings$team == home_team]),
         TRUE ~ sample_1)
sample_2 <- as.vector(sample(random_numbers, 1, replace = TRUE))
upcoming_games_df <- upcoming_games_df %>%
  mutate(away_rating = case_when(away_team %in% PrevWeek_VoA$team ~ Ratings$Rating[Ratings$team == away_team]),
         TRUE ~ sample_2)
```

I originally had the sample(random_numbers) inside of the mutate() function but I got error "must be a vector, not a `formula` object." So I moved it outside the mutate() function and added the as.vector(), but it still gave me the same error. I also got a warning about "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length". I don't know what to do now. The code above is the last thing I tried before coming here for help.

Comment: Hmm it looks like your "case_when" parenthesis doesn't include the "TRUE ~sample_1". If its still not solved, could you add an example of the data?

Answer (score 0):

`case_when` requires all arguments to be of same length. `sample_1` or `sample_2` have a length of 1 and it can get recycled.  (`as.vector` is not needed as `rnorm` returns a `vector`).

In addition, when we use `==`, it is elementwise comparison and can be used only when the length of both the columns compared are same or one of them have a length of 1 (i.e. it gets recycled).  Thus `Ratings$team == home_team` would be the cause of `longer object length` warning.

Instead of `case_when`, this maybe done with a join (assuming the 'team' column in 'Ratings' is not duplicated)

```
library(dplyr)
upcoming_games_df2 <- upcoming_games_df %>%
   left_join(Ratings, by = c("home_team" = "team")) %>%
   mutate(home_rating = coalesce(Rating, sample_1), team = NULL) %>%
   left_join(PrevWeek_VoA, by = c("away_team" = "team")) %>%
   mutate(away_rating = coalesce(Rating, sample_2))
```